# Can I use ATtiny SPI and still be able to do in-system programming?

Tags: avr, spi, attiny

I'm building a cost sensitive device that requires SPI and a single analogue comparator. Looking at the spec, ATtiny20 or ATtiny48 would fit the bill. The requirement is to be able to program it in circuit, however if I understand correctly, AVR Dragon programmer is also using SPI. Is it possible to use SPI for my requirements and program MCU at the same time?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Just not literally "at the same time", i.e. your SPI-connected peripherals are required to behave under the programming condition. Usually, all that is required would be that your circuit keeps the peripherals' SPI CE disengaged during programming.

Comment: FYI, one thing *not to do* is to imagine that you can leave an AVR-based ISP programmer connected to the circuit while you try it if you merely hold the programmer's AVR in reset "to get it out of the way."  I managed to inadvertently de-program the board I was using as an ISP by doing that!  Fortunately I was able to fix it by using yet another as an ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. [AVR042](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-2521-avr-hardware-design-considerations_applicationnote_avr042.pdf), "AVR Hardware Design Considerations" covers (among other topics) how the SPI lines should be designed in order to share them between both ISP and external peripherals.

Comment: Thanks. That is a very useful document. If I understand correctly, I have two options - either disconnect the other device from SPI while programming or place resistors on the lines. Do you know what size resistors would typically be sufficient?

Comment: That would depend on your programmer's drive strength and the "dead" input impedance of the peripheral(s).